# How do i correctly loop through the my list to display the information using Razor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have been struggling to loop through my private static List in my HomeController to display in such a way it shows a list of both students and personnel. Below is an example of what my loop should look like.

1. [Student] Name:John Surname:Greenberg Email: 123@123 Cellphone:123456789 Age: 20
2. [Personnel] Name:Rose Surname:Marry Email: email@email Cellphone:123456789 WorkerType: Permanent Degree: BED Education
3. [Student] Name:Chaz Surname:Brown Email: chazz@gmail.com Cellphone:123456789 Age: 30

Please help me loop properly and Below is my ContestantView i tried coding

```
@model List<Assignment9_u14333393.Models.ContestantViewModel>



<div style="width:100%;height:auto; background-color:brown; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;">
    <h2 style="text-align:center; color:white;">List of Contestants</h2>
</div>
  .
<div class="members" >
    <table>
        @foreach (var temp in Model)
        {

            <div class="member">
                [@temp.MemberType]  Name:@temp.Name  Surname:@temp.Surname  Email: @temp.Email Cellphone:@temp.CellPhone

            </div>

        }

    </table>
</div>
```

For additional information I also have three models (StudentViewModel, PersonnelViewModel and ContestantViewModel).
ContestantViewModel is my parent class and StudentViewModel and PersonnelViewModel are my classes which have inherited data members and properties for the parent class.

1st Model

```
public class ContestantViewModel
    {
        //Data members
        private string mName;
        private string mSurname;
        private string mCellPhone;
        private string mEmail;
        private string mMemberType;


        //Defeaut Constructor
        public ContestantViewModel()
        {
            mName = "NoName";
            mSurname = "NoSurname";
            mCellPhone = "NoCellNumber";
            mEmail = "NoEmail";
            mMemberType = "NoMemberType";
        }

        //Constructor
        public ContestantViewModel(string Name, string Surname, string CellPhone, string Email, string MemberType)
        {
            mName = Name;
            mSurname = Surname;
            mCellPhone = CellPhone;
            mEmail = Email;
            mMemberType = MemberType;
        }

        //Properties
        public string Name
        {
            get { return mName; }
            set { mName = value; }
        }
        public string Surname
        {
            get { return mSurname; }
            set { mSurname = value; }
        }
        public string CellPhone
        {
            get { return mCellPhone; }
            set { mCellPhone = value; }
        }
        public string Email
        {
            get { return mEmail; }
            set {mEmail = value; }
        }

        public string MemberType
        { 
             get; set;
        }
    }
```

2rd Model

```
public class PersonnelViewModel : ContestantViewModel
{
    private string mWorkerType;
    private string mDegree;


    public PersonnelViewModel(string Name, string Surname, string CellPhone, string Email, string MemberType, string WorkerType, string Degree) : base (Name,Surname,CellPhone,Email, MemberType)
    {
        mWorkerType = WorkerType;
        mDegree = Degree;
    }

    public PersonnelViewModel()
    {
        mWorkerType = "NoWorkerType";
        mDegree = "NoDegree";
    }

    public string WorkerType
    {
        get { return mWorkerType;}
        set { mWorkerType = value; }
    }

    public string Degree
    {
        get { return mDegree; }
        set { mDegree = value; }
    }
}
```

3rd Model

```
 public class StudentViewModel : ContestantViewModel
    {
    //Data members
    private int mAge;

    //D Constructor
    public StudentViewModel()
    {
        mAge = 0;

    }


    //Constructor
    public StudentViewModel(string Name, string Surname, string CellPhone, string Email, string MemberType, int Age) : base(Name, Surname, CellPhone, Email, MemberType)
    {
        mAge = Age;
    }

    //properties
    public int Age
    {
        get { return mAge; } set { mAge = value; }
    }
}
```

and this is my controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // list to hold all my new members
        private static List<ContestantViewModel> List = new List<ContestantViewModel>();

        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }
        // GET: Signup
        public ActionResult Signup(string Name, string Surname, string Email, string Cellphone, string MemberType, int Age,string WorkerType,string Degree)
        {
            StudentViewModel Stundent = new StudentViewModel();
            PersonnelViewModel Personnel = new PersonnelViewModel();
            if (MemberType == "Student")
            {
                //creates instance
                Stundent.Name = Name;
                Stundent.Surname = Surname;
                Stundent.Email = Email;
                Stundent.CellPhone = Cellphone;
                Stundent.MemberType = MemberType;
                Stundent.Age = Age;
                // Add data to list
                List.Add(Stundent);
            }
            else
            {
                //creates instance
                Personnel.Name = Name;
                Personnel.Surname = Surname;
                Personnel.Email = Email;
                Personnel.CellPhone = Cellphone;
                Personnel.MemberType = MemberType;
                Personnel.WorkerType = WorkerType;
                Personnel.Degree = Degree;
                // Add data to list
                List.Add(Personnel);
            }

            return View(List);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your collection into it's own view model instead of trying to reference it with this line:

```
@model List<Assignment9_u14333393.Models.ContestantViewModel>
```

Make a new view model, ViewModelCollections with a collection of your ContestantViewModel.  Something like

```
List<ContestantViewModel> ContestantList
```

(you can also add others, like your students and workers and reuse the model, even if for some purposes some collections are empty)

Then reference that with:

```
@model ViewModelCollections
```

Once you have put all your contestants into the collection you are very close in your current view code.

```
<div class="members">
        <table id="contestantListTable">
            <tbody>

                @* Column Headers *@
                <tr class="contestantListHeaders">
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                </tr>

                @* Content Rows *@
                @foreach (var temp in Model.ContestantList)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@temp.mName</td>
                        <td>@temp.mSurName</td>
                        <td>@temp.mEmail</td>
                        <td>@temp.mCellPhone</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Instead of this saying "Name:  Contestant"   "LastName:  #1"  etc etc

You will have a table:

```
First Name  |  Last Name  |  Email  etc etc
Contestant  |  #1         | ...
.
.
.
```